# How to change input placeholder text with css

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I need to change the placeholder text of an input textbox via css.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="col">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" id="myID">
</div>
```

And here is the css one:

```
#myID::placeholder{content:"Type something";}
```

I can't write the placeholder directly inside the html code and not even with JS. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: you can't and you shouldn't. Input is a replace element and `::before` and `::after` does not apply to replaced elements. For accessibility reasons you even shouldn't try to hack it. If you want to hack it, apply the pseudo-element to the wrapping element.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me a code example?

Comment: @tacoshy It's not the same, placeholder is not mentioned

Comment: well ti is related and explains why your attempt can't work.

Comment: `<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Type here" id="myID">` You are welcome!

Comment: Try this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_placeholder.asp

Comment: @jkalandarov - You may have misunderstood the question.  In some environments we may have limited modify permissions, e.g., like a corporate portal. So the solution becomes more complex than just adding a placeholder attribute to the input.

Comment: Trying to change the `textContent` of the DOM element with CSS???

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments, you can not use `pseudo-elements` on replaced elements such as input (or images). So you have to apply it to the wrapping element. A method with many downsides that need more solutions and fixed that are caused by the hack:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block; /* reduces the width to the input */
  position: relative; 
}

div::after {
  content: "type something";
  position: absolute; 
  inset: 0; /* uses the same size as the div */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: -1; /* moves the placeholder to the background and makes the inptu clickable */
}

input {
  background: transparent; /* required to see the placehodler while in the background */
}

input:focus {
  background: white; /* hides the placeholder on focus */
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" id="myID">
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent solution given all the constraints. +1  I tried using [::placeholder-shown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown) with your code to toggle the input background color.  Yet, I couldn't make it work when the placeholder is an empty string. So I think this solution is as good as you can make it.

Comment: Try it as `:placeholder-shown`. ONE `:`.

Comment: @NerdyDeeds I think you miss the actual question here. The OP can not add a placeholder in HTML. As such the `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-selector has no effect here as we do not work with placeholders in the first place.

Comment: @tacoshy And I think you miss the fact that my reply was to Yogi, the comment immediately above mine, complaining that, when trying to solve his own, presumably-unrelated issue he was struggling to make `::placeholder-shown` work. I was pointing out that, since it's a pseudo-CLASS and not a pseudo-ELEMENT, (https://mzl.la/41qEKYb) he would be better served trying it with a single `:`